# AndEngine AreaTouched method to move sprite is delayed

Tags: android, andengine

I am using this method to move a sprite side to side in AndEngine.

```
Sprite player = new Sprite(PlayerX,PlayerY, this.mPlayerTextureRegion) {

   @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                                 final float pTouchAreaLocalX,
                                 final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
        this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2,
                         this.getY());
        return true;
     }
};
```

Thr problem i am noticing is that when the sprite is moved swiftly back and forth there is a delay and sometimes it wont move until retouched and dragged.

Is there anyway to optimize this for better performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ive figured it out from the AndEngine code.

Dont forget when using onAreaTouched() to move sprites to call

```
 mScene.setTouchAreaBindingEnabled(true)
```

At the end of your LoadScene() method.